# Is there an equivalent to cron in Windows?

Tags: php, windows, cron

I want to know if there is an equivalent `cron` in Windows and how I can use it programmatically using PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows has the `Scheduled Tasks` control panel applet (or management console plug-in on later versions of Windows) but you can also access it via [`schtasks.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596) if you want to automate it from the command line.

In addition, you can also use [`at`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Windows%29) from the command line to schedule a task.